# React tilt library

Tags: reactjs, three.js, vite

The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-tilt.js?t=1681239019006&v=59c21aef' does not provide an export named 'default

I tried reinstalling tilt again using npm still it didnt make any difference
i also tried to uninstall the react-tilt library and again importing like this import Tilt from "react-tilt" but does solve the problem same error is coming out

i tried to solve the error because my browser does show the page of website which i'm trying to display it show me the blank page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.